# How to change value of xpath dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I have the following element, and i would like to click on each tab and check if value is present inside the input field, i would like to avoid creating each WebElement for each Language

[image]

[image]

Could somebody kindly let me know how to go about it. Otherwise i end up instatiating element for each language and performing a click and checking the text area so if xpath or css can be manipulated it would be awesome

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'dynamically changeable language')]
```

Thank you so much in advance guys.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use class name attribute to select all elements as list and then iterate over it:

```
"//div[starts-with(@class,'tabbedTextarea_TabButton')]"
```

Comment: @FindBy(xpath = "//div[starts-with(@class,'tabbedTextarea_TabButton')]")
    public List<WebElement> listOfLanguageButtons;  -> 0 elements located

Comment: @Prozorov , How about `tabbedTextarea__TabButton` - it's not clear how many underscores there are on screenshot... (It's better to add HTML as text)

Comment: @JaSON you right it works like that     @FindBy(xpath ="//div[starts-with(@class,'tabbedTextarea__TabButton')]")
 Is there a way to use starts with by locating by css ->     @FindBy(css ="*[starts-with(@class,'tabbedTextarea__TabButton')]")
?

Comment: @Prozorov in CSS the same would look like `"div[class^='tabbedTextarea__TabButton']"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating over the elements using for loop.

E.g.

List links =@FindAll(xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'dynamically changeable language'));

```
for(int i =0; i<=links.length; i++){
@Find(xpath = "(//div[contains(text(),'dynamically changeable language)[i]'));

//hear click and check the text
}
```

You can also use for each loop, if you want to avoid using the above for loop, but it might give you stale element error.